# app engine URL class logging warning

Tags: java, google-app-engine

What is the preferred method of fetching a url and it's content in app-engine?

This is how I'm doing it now:

```
URL google = new URL("http://www.google.com");
google.openStream();
```

and this is the warning I get

```
Mar 6, 2010 4:11:50 AM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase getResponseBody
WARNING: Going to buffer response body of large or unknown size.
         Using getResponseBodyAsStream instead is recommended.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is only a problem of the development server. Do you get this message on the production server as well?

In any case, the API you are using is the official way to fetch URL content.

Comment: I've not pushed to production yet. It hadn't crossed my mind that it wouldn't happen in prod(I try not to let my mind go there).